# 'stray \223 and \224 error' and other errors in C

Tags: c

I've gotten some stray errors with some other errors, and I have no idea why:

> [Error] stray '\223' in program
>
> [Error] stray '\224' in program In function 'int
> readData(GymRecord**)':
>
> [Error] 'q2' was not declared in this scope
>
> [Error] request for member 'name' in '*(dir + ((long long unsigned
> int)(((long long unsigned int)k) * 8ull)))', which is of non-class
> type 'GymRecord*'
>
> [Error] request for member 'age' in '*(dir + ((long long unsigned
> int)(((long long unsigned int)k) * 8ull)))', which is of non-class
> type 'GymRecord*'

```
int readData(struct GymRecord *dir[]){

    FILE *fdir = fopen(“q2.txt”, "r");
    char buff[MBUFF];
    int k = 0;

    while(k<MDIR && fgets(buff, MBUFF-1, fdir)){
        strcpy(dir[k].name,strtok(buff, ","));
        dir[k].age = atol(strtok(NULL, "\n"));
        k++;
    }

    return(k);
}
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting should help you...

Comment: A much more direct analysis is to realise ‘\223’ ‘\224’ are octal → CE /CP-1250 [0x93 and 0x94](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250#Character_set)  → U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You must have pasted some nicely-formated text from a website, but the compiler wants plain text. The problem is with your `“` and `”` characters. Replace them with ordinary quotes, `"`, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Your quotes for the filename are the wrong ones. This line

```
FILE *fdir=fopen(“q2.txt”,"r");
```

Needs to be

```
FILE *fdir=fopen("q2.txt","r");
```